# Preenchimento de input com o dia da semana de acordo com a data no input anterior

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Criei dois inputs. O primeiro atribuí a data já pré-preenchida desta forma:

```
<strong><label for="Data">Data Reserva</label></strong>
<input type="date" id="Data" name="Data" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>"/>
```

Pretendia que o segundo input preenchesse o dia da semana de acordo com a data que seleccionei no input anterior:

```
<strong><label for="Dia">Dia da Semana/Utilização</label></strong>
<input type="text" id="Dia" name="Dia" style="width:220px"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode utilizar um evento `change` no input da data e inserir o dia da semana no outro input sempre que você alterá-lo.

Mas você deverá utilizar o objeto `Date()` para extrair o dia da semana da data no input. No caso eu fiz um split na data, que está no formato `aaaa-mm-dd`, para construir o objeto `Date(ano, mês, dia)`, e com `.getDay()` se obtém o valor numérico referente ao dia da semana, que é puxado o nome segundo a posição na array:

```
$(function(){

   $("#Data").on("change", function(){

      var d = this.value.split("-");
      var data = new Date(d[0], d[1]-1, d[2]).getDay();
      var dia_semana = ['DOM', 'SEG', 'TER', 'QUA', 'QUI', 'SEX', 'SÁB'][data];
      $("#Dia").val(dia_semana);

   }).change();

});
```

**Exemplo de funcionamento:**

```js
$(function(){
   
   $("#Data").on("change", function(){
      
      var d = this.value.split("-");
      var data = new Date(d[0], d[1]-1, d[2]).getDay();
      var dia_semana = ['DOM', 'SEG', 'TER', 'QUA', 'QUI', 'SEX', 'SÁB'][data];
      $("#Dia").val(dia_semana);
      
   }).change();
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong><label for="Data">Data Reserva</label></strong>
<input type="date" id="Data" name="Data" value="2019-04-23"/>
<br>
<strong><label for="Dia">Dia da Semana/Utilização</label></strong>
<input type="text" id="Dia" name="Dia" style="width:220px"/>
```